# Security testing alternatives on MacOS

Tags: kali-linux, macos, terminal

Is it possible/feasible to set up a hacking machine that rivals a distribution like Kali Linux on MacOS, or will it never be possible for MacOS to rival a distribution like Kali in terms of hacking tools and functionality from CLI?

Comment: There should be no inherent limit in what MacOS (or probably even Windows) can do in order to offer similar capabilities. This does not mean that it is trivial and depending on what functionality you exactly need even writing OS drivers to support specific hardware might be needed. Anyway, I don't see this question really as asking about an information security problem, i.e. don't feel it is on-topic here.

Comment: All the tools in Kali are open source and from sources that are not unique to the Kali maintainers.

Comment: @schroeder is there any way I could send you an individual message or email with a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand the difference between Operating System and Applications/Utilities and also concept of Open-Source. Kali Linux is based on Debian (Linux O/S) and comes with many pre-installed security testing tools. Offensive Security who maintains the Kali Linux project can tweak the source code, if need be to accommodate different tools. For example, Kali also has a custom-built kernel that is patched for 802.11 wireless injection [(Refer this)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux). This is not possible with closed-source MacOS, unless Apple Inc. decides to do so. Said that, I easily find installers for most common tools for MacOS as well, if it's popular. However, you can always use Kali Linux as a Virtual Machine over MacOS.

Comment: My follow up question would be is there a package or tool for macOS that targets cell phone vulnerabilities. I already have Kali dual booted and it does its job in terms of computer to computer pentesting.

Comment: I have used Genymotion Android emulator on MacOS. However it's just provides an interface and doesn't check for vulnerabilities.

Comment: Hmm ok. This attack was done to me and I am trying to figure out how it happened. Fair enough.